# Angular how to send form values to a service and from service to database?

Tags: angular

I am working this project and learning angular at the same time.

I have a deal form (something to do with restaurants) and after i click the save button, it sends the data to the database. It works fine.

I have a model named DealModel and i have a AddDeal component and what i want to do here is rather than sending the form values from the component i should use a service, so what i am confused about is how do i send the values first to the service (from service to db is trivial since it's already implemented)

here is a look at the function
PS: i believed that i should leave it the way it is, but the team want a service for maintenance purposes i guess

```
  enregistrerDeal() {
    //sorry some of it in French.
    //these are just form values.
    this.Restaurant = new Etablissement();
    this.Restaurant.id=this.selectedValue;

    const deal:Deal = {
    titre: this.dealForm.controls['titre'].value,
    dateD : this.dealForm.controls['dateD'].value,
    dateF :this.dealForm.controls['dateF'].value,
    descriptif: this.dealForm.controls['descriptif'].value,
    //images:this.dealForm.controls['images'].value,
    prixActuel: this.dealForm.controls['prixActuel'].value,
    nombreDeals:this.dealForm.controls['nombreDeals'].value,
    etablissement: this.Restaurant, //this.dealForm.controls['etablissement'].value,
    disponibilite: this.dealForm.controls['disponibilite'].value,
    } 
    this.notif.messege = 'gerant ' + this.Restaurant.id + ' a ajoute un deal à' + this.EtablissementsByGerant.nom;

    //console.log("la valeur est"+this.dealForm.controls['etablissement'].value);

    //here it does send it to spring?
    this.http.post(this.apiUrls.addDeal, deal ,
      {
        headers: new HttpHeaders()
          .set("Content-Type", "application/json")
      }
    )
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          //console.log(deal);
          //console.log("la valeur du resteau ajoutée est"+this.dealForm.controls['etablissement'].value);
         // window.location.reload();
         this.toastr.success('votre deal a ete ajouter ');
         this.http.get('http://localhost:8081/api/notify/' + this.notif.messege, {
           headers: new HttpHeaders()
             .set("Content-Type", "application/json")
         })
           .subscribe(
             (data: any) => {
               console.log('notif envoye');
             }
           )
         this.router.navigate(['displayDeals']);

       // console.log(deal);
        } );
        //console.log(deal);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `DealService` that implement `addDeal` function. 
Services should handle the logic in your app. (in these case to take a deal and put it in the server)

creat DealSerivece with the angualr cli : `ng generate service Deal`
and add addDeal function to the service
Result :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DealService {

  constructor() { }

  addDeal(deal:Deal) {
     // here you need to do the post request to server (exactly as you did in the component just move it to here).
     // you can return an observable and subscribe in the component if you like
   }
 }
```

Import and inject `Dealservice` to your component and use the `addDeal` function from the service :

```
// deal.component.ts

import { Dealservice } from '../deal.service';

// just add the Dealservice 
constructor(private dealService: Dealservice ) { }

// now use the service in the right place:
enregistrerDeal(){
 ....
 ....
 ...
 const deal:Deal = { ... }
 this.dealService.addDeal(deal)
 // you can subscribe if you like to.. 
}
```

in `app.module.ts` you need to add your service to the providers array

```
import { DealService } from './deal.service';
providers : [DealService]
```

its based on the angular docs:
[Service docs](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)

Comment: Thank you so much this really helped me.

Comment: Just one last question if i may, the observer and subscription, from what i understand it's about a stream of input that are synchronous, so i use if i want all the data and not be blocked, do i need it in this example when i am sending a form input?

Comment: You are right. The obserbels are for asyncronised work. If your functions are syncronised you dosent need the observebels

Comment: one last question please, which is better, like i did above defined a deal model in the component and filled it with the form values then passed as parameter to the service, Or i define a deal model in the service and then in the component i type: this.dealservice.deal_model.descriptif = this.dealForm.controls['descriptif'].value

Comment: I think its very personal. I prefer that my services gets the models of the app (like you did here) and not bunch of fields.